# Windows 7 locked out of account

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10

I think an update to ie10 stuffed my settings.

I got a message saying I was not authorised to use files for ie, avg etc so basically everything was toast.

I managed to uninstall ie and then got response again.

When I logged in to my user it said I was not authorised and made me log in as TEMP.

I log in as user XXXX, and all my settings etc how I used to have them are in (Example for chrome bookmarks)

C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

But in reality I am using the settings, favourites, desktop etc for user TEMP - eg my chrome bookmarks are being used ffrom ...

C:\Users\TEMP\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Does anyone know how to restore the settings back to my user XXXX ?

No data is missing, it is just inaccessable.

Comment: Create a new user account.  Take ownership of the files in the old profile folder, replace profile file data in new profile with old data, works every time.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this problem a few times now, the way I have gone about recovering the local profile is by doing a simple registry fix. It would be hard to explain but the following link I have bookmarked will guide you step by step in how to resolve your issue.

http://www.sysprobs.com/fix-temporary-profile-windows-7

Comment: I have seen this a few times and can confirm that this does work...

Comment: @AshKing - We really expect more then a link to a solution.  The linked website could go down which then makes your answer in a non-useful state.